# Emacs - Is it possible to have a save history of a file?

Tags: emacs, version-control, version, developer-tools

I want to know if there is a way to have file history in emacs.
With file history I mean:

- List all the times a file has been saved.
- View the diff between the current file and the file in that version.
- Revert file to that version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple version system in emacs for individual text files, quoted from: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevisionControlSystem

```
"To put a file under VersionControl with RCS type ‘C-x v v’ (‘vc-next-action’).

After making edits,
view the changes with `C-x v =’ (‘vc-diff’).
or check in the revision by typing another ‘C-x v v’.

After entering a log message, complete the check-in with ‘C-c C-c’ (‘vc-finish-logentry’).
Instead of checking in, undo your changes with ‘C-x v u’ (‘vc-revert-buffer’).
At any moment, view a file’s revision log with ‘C-x v l’ (‘vc-print-log’). "
```

But i think there are more robust and proved options like the integration with git, or the undo-tree https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree
(it looks like this:)[image]

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.